# Git error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)

Tags: git, heroku

While I can normally do commits and also `push` to other remote repositories (eg. Github), but when I try a `git push heroku master` I get this error:

```
    error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
    fatal: loose object ae1711b15b2793ae756797eebdfafc051d52a215 (stored in .git/objects/ae/1711b15b2793ae756797eebdfafc051d52a215) is corrupt
```

If I do a `git fsck --no-dangling` I get the same message.

These are the heroku remotes:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:fppis.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:fppis.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly caused the issue, but I solved this by cloning the GitHub remote into a new local repository and pushing that again to Heroku.